# what is the meaning of this kind of error and y do i get it?(syntax error, unexpected 'reqiure' (T_STRING) )

Tags: php, html, mysql, connection

after establishing the connection I'm getting this kind of error in my PHP extension file. I have also tried in otherways but I get this kind of error.

Comment: Hello, can u edit your question to have the source code and any more detail information. So everyone can have better understanding about your problem

Answer (score 1):

You just mis-spelled "require".
Use any of these:

```php
require 'path/to/script.php'
require('path/to/script.php')
require_once 'path/to/script.php'
require_once('path/to/script.php')
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for the word "reqiure" in the code and replace it with `require`.
You are getting this error because the PHP parser does not expect that string token at that point in the syntax.

From the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php), this is what a T_STRING is:

> identifiers, e.g. keywords like parent and self, function names, class names and more are matched. See also T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING.